# Is it possible to convert a JSON file to React with Quikctype?

Tags: json, reactjs, quicktype

I am trying to convert a JSON file into React components. I stumbled across Quicktype and it seems like it can convert JSON to Javascript. I'm wondering if anyone knows if there is a way for it to go a level deeper, and somehow create React code.

If not, is there any other software that might exist to tackle this problem?

Comment: It doesn't "convert JSON to JavaScript", it converts JSON to code that can read that JSON. There would be no way to generically "convert" JSON to React components because JSON is data, and data has different meaning(s) in different applications. In order for this question to have any meaning you'd need to actually describe what you want.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to clarify. I want to have a JSON file that could be formatted in any way, and somehow convert it into react components. An example of a react component I would like to create could be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) in the first example. This problem seems really hard though so I'm not sure if it's possible

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. You can transform JSON to anything you want, including JS code; that you want React is irrelevant. You've provided zero criteria indicating what you want to do with *anything* in the JSON, so there's no way anybody could provide any meaningful input.

Comment: I am assuming that the JSON will be formatted in a way that it contains information like creation of functions and actual lines of code somehow. I want to convert these types of things into code. Unfortunately, I don't have a solid grasp on how that is going to be formatted exactly because I'm still not sure how to implement this task, so the format for the JSON is up in the air as well. But the point of the JSON is to somehow specify what I want the react to look like. Should I give a mock code example of what I'm looking for?

Comment: Um... if it already has code in it then why not just write the code? Without any sort of mockup it's impossible to know what you have in mind, or if it even makes any sense. It sounds like you're trying to automate code creation, which almost never ends well.

Comment: You guessed it, I am trying to automate code creation! I want to allow a user to send in a json to my program, and have my program spit out a react component created from some form of specifications inside the json. Just wondering, why doesn't automating code ever end well?

Comment: Because by the time you allow for customization it's quicker, easier, and more useful to just write the code. And as soon as you want to extend the provided functionality the generated code is no longer relevant, and re-generating is fraught. If it's just a simple template, and you don't want any sort of two-way interop, it can help to shell something else, but... meh.